# Vercel build never ends

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I'm having a problem with **Vercel** platform, probably because I'm not using it right.

Locally I can deploy the server without problems on port 3000.
But when I want to deploy in Vercel, **Build** gets stuck at the *express* function app.listen().

Image Vercel error:
[image: Image Vercel error]

My *index.js* is like any other and ends with the function:

```
// listening the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port ', app.get('port'));
});
```

I've tried everything I don't know what to do anymore, surely I have a conceptual error.

Comment: This should not be part of your build process, rather your index file should only be run when the server is already built.

Comment: How does your package.json look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vercel is for front-end (and serverless)

Sites deployed on Vercel are mainly front-end. (React, Vue, and everything else that becomes HTML/CSS/JS).

By the looks of it you're trying to run a back-end application (Node.js) on Vercel, which it isn't designed for. (Instead, consider using a VPS or a managed environment/app platform)

Vercel also supports [serverless functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions), which you could use to run your back-end with. These are essentially one-off functions that are run **on a new server instance** every time a request comes in.

All that considered, if you're indeed trying to build and deploy a front-end app...

##### A wild guess

Your build script is calling your node application. You might have something like the following in your `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc && node src"
}
```

This would run `tsc` first, then start the application by running the built files.

However, you don't want to start your application as part of the build process -- instead, make the build command *only* build your app, nothing more.

Then, on Vercel, go to your project's settings page and make sure that command is used to Build your app.

##### My app doesn't need to be built (I've already got plain HTML/CSS/JS files)

If your app doesn't need to be built at all, go to your project's settings page and remove the "Build Command" entirely.

Comment: It's true, now I realize that my app will only run on a VPS. I am quite new in Web Development, I come from the low-level programming environment and Im not used to this frameworks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Another possible solution

For me it was just that I forgot to add the `vercel.json` in to my project.

I had to add this to my root directory.

```js
{   
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      { "src": "*.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }
    ],
    "routes": [
        { "src": "/.*", "dest": "/" }
    ],
    "regions": [
        "sfo1"
    ]
}
```

For those who don't know what that is exactly:
https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration